# $sum using Mongo DB aggreagation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document as Follows:

{_id:1,"$field1":10,"$field2":20}

Through mongo db java driver, can we update all the documents with a new field called $total which would sum of field1 and field2

THe equivalent in Relation database would like

Update table set total=field1+field2

Is the same possible using mongo DB java driver without fetching records one by one.

I have tried the following link and it doesnt give the result as specified in the link

**https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/**

```
db.students.insert({ "_id": 1, "quizzes": [ 10, 6, 7 ], "labs": [ 5, 8 ], "final": 80, "midterm": 75 });
db.students.insert({ "_id": 2, "quizzes": [ 9, 10 ], "labs": [ 8, 8 ], "final": 95, "midterm": 80 });
db.students.insert({ "_id": 3, "quizzes": [ 4, 5, 5 ], "labs": [ 6, 5 ], "final": 78, "midterm": 70 });
```

**Query:**

```
db.students.aggregate([
   {
     $project: {
       quizTotal: { $sum: "$quizzes"},
       labTotal: { $sum: "$labs" },
       examTotal: { $sum: [ "$final", "$midterm" ] }
     }
   }
])
```

Result memntioned in the docs:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "quizTotal" : 23, "labTotal" : 13, "examTotal" : 155 }
{ "_id" : 2, "quizTotal" : 19, "labTotal" : 16, "examTotal" : 175 }
{ "_id" : 3, "quizTotal" : 14, "labTotal" : 11, "examTotal" : 148 }
```

Acutal Result:

```
assert: command failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$sum'",
    "code" : 15999,
    "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
Error: command failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$sum'",
    "code" : 15999,
    "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:11:14)
    at Function.assert.commandWorked (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:254:5)
    at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1278:12)
    at (shell):1:13
2016-02-06T09:58:49.230+0530 E QUERY    Error: command failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$sum'",
    "code" : 15999,
    "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:11:14)
    at Function.assert.commandWorked (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:254:5)
    at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1278:12)
    at (shell):1:13 at src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13
>
```

Comment: Did you read this on the page *"Changed in version 3.2: $sum is available in the $group and $project stages. In previous versions of MongoDB, $sum is available in the $group stage only."*. So if your MongoDB server version is not 3.2 then it does not work in this way with arrays. Also the final field should use `$add` anyway. i.e `"$add": [ "$final", "$midterm" ]`, generally speaking, though the usage does accomodate this now. And the shell is JavaScript, which is a different language to Java.

Comment: Thanks @BlakesSeven . I was checking on how to achieve the above specified query using mongoDB java driver.I was making the query in shell just to check how to use the operators.As u suggested  db.students.aggregate([    {      $project: {          examTotal: { $add: [ "$final", "$midterm" ] }      }    } ])..This query is working fine in shell..can the same be achived using MongoDB java driver

Comment: If you want to ask a question about Java then ask a question about Java. This was not, and you only get one question at a time. Notation is just basic lists and DBObject ( or BSON Document Obects for the 3.x driver series and greater ) . It's really quite simple. But the newer usage for `$sum` requires a MongoDB 3.2 server, which is why you see the errors shown above.

Comment: Thanks @BlakesSeven Posted a different question..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240667/how-to-do-multiple-aggregation-operations-in-mongoquery-and-update-the-field-in