# How to do multiple aggregation operations in MongoQuery and Update the field in a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In RDBMS, suppose we have 4 columns , say `col1, col2, col3, col4`

If we want `col4` value to be `col1 + col2 - col3`,
we can write an update statement as follows:

```
Update Table set col4=col1+col2-col3
```

Is doing multiple operations possibe using Mongo shell aggregation?

I tried to get the sum of two fields using aggregation with following query.

```
db.students.aggregate([    
    {      
        $project: { examTotal: { $add: [ "$final", "$midterm" ] } }
    },
    { $out: "students" }
])
```

But with this query its replacing the fields in the same collection. How could this be achieved?

`col4=col1+col2-col3` and update the `col4` value in same collection. Can this be possible within a single step?

Comment: In your [very last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35237254/sum-using-mongo-db-aggreagation?noredirect=1#comment58195298_35237254) you were given a note specifically saying *"you can only ask one question at a time here"*. So why are you including "also" with another question here? This should be a simple case. StackOverflow = Q&A Forum = "One question and one accepted answer to that question". You cannot keep asking multiple questions in one. Not a discussion forum here. One clear question only please. You were already asked nicely.

Comment: @BlakesSeven..Thank you..Updated the question..

Comment: You still really should have looked a little harder at the documentation. Look at [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) and think about how you need to construct here.

Comment: Thanks @BlakesSeven for the reference in documentation...Updated the second question in  a seperated thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35241567/get-the-count-of-fields-in-each-document-through-query-using-mongodb-java-driver