# Get the count of Fields in each document through query using MongoDB java driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

Is it possible to get the number of fields in document using a Query From MongoDB java Driver

Example:

```
 Document1 :{_id:1,"type1": 10 "type2":30,"ABC":123,"DEF":345}
 Document2 :{_id:2,"type2":30,"ABC":123,"DEF":345}
```

Note:  In second document "type1"  key doesnt exist .

When i project

Is it possible to project only "type1" and "type2" and get number of fields existing in that document.

With current code i am getting all the documents and individually searching if there is the key i am looking is present in the whole cursor:
The code snipped is as follows:

```
MongoClient mcl=new MongoClient();
MongoDatabase mdb=mcl.getDatabase("test");
MongoCollection mcol=mdb.getCollection("testcol");
FindIterable<Document> findIterable = mcol.find();
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = findIterable.iterator();
//Here am having 120 types checking if each type is present..
while(cursor.hasNext())
{

Document doc=cursor.next();
int numberOfTypes=0;
for(int i=1;i<=120;i++)
{
if(doc.containsKey("type"+i))
{
numberOfTypes++;
}
}
System.out.println("*********************************************");
System.out.println("_id"+doc.get("_id"));
    System.out.println("Number of Types in this document are "+numberOfTypes);
System.out.println("*********************************************");
    }

}
```

This code is working if the records are less it wont be over load to the application ..Suppose there are 5000000 with each Document containing 120 types , the application is crashing as there would be more garbage collection involved as for every iteration we are creating a document.Is there any other approach through which we can achieve the above stated functionality.

Answer (score 0):

From your java code I read

> project only "type1" and "type2" and get number of fields existing in that document.

as

```
project only type[1..120] fields and number of such fields in the document
```

With this assumption, you can [map-reduce](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/) it as following:

```
db.testcol.mapReduce(
function(){
    value = {count:0};
    for (i = 1; i <= 120; i++) {
        key = "type" + i
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            value[key] = this[key];
            value.count++
       }
    }
    if (value.count > 0) {
        emit(this._id, value);
    }
},
function(){
    //nothing to reduce
},
{
    out:{inline:true}
});
```

`out:{inline:true}` works for small datasets, when result fits into [16Mb limit](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#limit-bson-document-size). For larger responses you need to `output` to a collection, which you can query and iterate as usual.